# Cancel reloading of language

Tags: node.js, express, i18next

I use i18next in my node app to internazionalize it.

My settings :

```
i18next.init({
    load: 'current',
    saveMissing: true,
    sendMissingTo : 'all',
    ignoreRoutes: ['img/','images/', 'public/', 'css/', 'js/'],
    debug: true,
    supportedLngs: ['en-US', 'fr-FR'],
    fallbackLng: 'fr-FR'
});
```

On the client side I have two links for changing the language :

```
<a href="/setLanguage/en-US">English</a>
<a href="/setLanguage/fr-FR">Francais</a>
```

and on the server side I catch the two possibilities (I change the language ad redirect to the Welcome page):

```
app.get('/setLanguage/:lng', function(req, res){
    console.log('Change language : ' + req.params.lng);
    i18next.setLng(req.params.lng, function(){
           res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

The problem is point 2 :

1. that change correctly the selected language
2. redirecting to the '/' reload the language to default value.

How to not reload it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910398/cancel-reloading-of-language), you have the following options:

- add `?setLng=<language>` to URL
- setting i18next cookie

[`setLng` method was removed.](https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next-node/issues/46)

Comment: Hum ok thanks for the information... I have seen these two others options but can't implement one of them... how to adding the parameters to every url dynamically ? and how to set and retrieve i18next cookie ?

Comment: Omg... I didn't understand that setting one time via URL will effect on all pages until browser is close!